# Debugger for MSIL or for exe-file created in .NET C#

Tags: .net, debugging, cil

I need to debug a program written in .NET C#.

Specifically - all I need is to see what the function returns after it's call. I found that I can use for this purpose Microsoft Visual Studio - it understand IL. I get the source code of that exe-file using ILDASM. Than I get pdb file and use ILASM to get exe-file from IL-code. But original exe file is differ from exe-file that I get after ILASM.

Program starts but I have AccessViolation цhen I try to execute the function, the result of which I need to see. Program is not obfuscated.

What I do wrong or what do I need to do to get successful result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various reasons why exe->il->exe might not work. A few other than the one you mentioned (obfuscated IL), are an executable that also includes native code, or a digitally signed executable that (directly or indirectly) inspects its own signature.

A few debuggers can step through IL without you having to rebuild the application. Personally, I like to use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) for this. Note that the binaries of the latest release don't include the bits needed for debugging, you need to build it from source for that.

An alternative should be MDbg: Mike Stall reports having added IL stepping to the GUI [back in 2005](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/11/15/updated-gui.aspx). I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

I used DILE several years ago: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dile/ and it did a really nice job of letting me step through the IL in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

[hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd) already explained what might go wrong when doing exe -> IL -> exe and I'm not going to dwell on it. However, I will give you a tip how to noninvasively check the return value of a function. First you need to enable native debugger for your project:

C# app:

[image]

ASP.NET:

[image]

Then place a breakpoint on the last line of your method, open Immediate Window and type (this needs to be done once per debugging session):

```
.load sos
```

Then step out of the function (Shift+F11) and copy the value of the `eax` (or `rax`) registry (Debug->Windows->Registers). If the return type of your function is a value type (int, byte, etc.) the value is right at your fingertips (you may paste it to the Watch Window to convert it to a decimal value). In case it's a reference value e(r)ax contains an address of the object in the heap. In order to view it get back to the Immediate Window and type:

!do [your copied e(r)ax value]

The object will be displayed with all its properties and fields in the Immediate Window. For strings you may also use the Debug->Windows->Memory window.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into Dile, as recommended by @Jason-Haley, I see it has gone stale and would no longer build.

The screen shots looked promising so I revived the old source code, upgrading it to VS2107, NETFXSDK\4.7.2 and the Windows 10 SDK Kit (the project currently has Windows dependencies).

After fixing some bugs and ironing out some compiler errors I managed to get it working andpublished a new GIT repo. https://github.com/alexhiggins732/DILE-MSIL-DEBUGGER